# How to change the color of a node based on changed data in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
nodes = g.append("g")
           .attr("class", "net_node")
           .selectAll("circle")
           .data(data).enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return color.palette(d.group);
                })
```

The nodes are defined as follows.

In the pallete, colors are assigned according to the group number.

I do not know the current method, so when other data is input, I delete the svg and run it again.

```
svg.remove();
view(new_data);
```

How to change nodes.data and change color

I've read a lot of posts and tried a lot but still can't figure out the answer

thank you.

Comment: So that you don't ` .style("fill", function (d) { return '#1f77b4'; })`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use it like that?

Comment: I'm not exaggerating when I say that what you're doing right now (which is removing everything for painting all the new elements) is almost similar to not using D3 at all! And apparently you know that, because you feel that this cannot be right. So, what you're missing is the very point of D3, which is the "enter-update-exit pattern". Try to google that and you'll find lots of good tutorials.